# How to show loader image when uploading file using codeigniter 3 file upload library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out a way using codeigniter file upload library.

View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/staff_bulk_upload_process', ['role' => 'form']); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 hidden">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/ajax-loader.gif"); ?>">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="staff_file">Import Staff Data</label>
           <input type="file" class="form-control" id="staff_file" name="staff_file" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="importStaff">Upload File</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My objective is to toggle the hidden/show class of bootstrap. So that when the file upload is in progress it should display the image and when it is done, image should be hidden.

controller:

```
public function staff_bulk_upload_process()
    {
        $this->load->model('welcomemodel/welcome_model');
        $time = substr(time(), 5);
        $file_name = 'staff_bulk_upload_file' . $time . '.csv';
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/staff/add/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $config['file_name'] = $file_name;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('staff_file'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('staff_import_message', '<div class="alert" role="alert">'.$error['error'].'</div>');
        }

        redirect('welcome');
    }
```

Comment: You can do it from client side only.

Comment: Can you tell me how ?